# Trying to prove the closure of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove that $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z,+)$ is closed with respect to $+$. My first thought was to use the definition of the set $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ which is $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z=\{[0]_{3},[1]_{3},[2]_{3}\}$

A set $S$ is closed if $\forall a,b\in S (a\star b) \in S$ for some equipped binary operation $\star$.

The possible combinations for values of a and b are:

$a=3k, b=3k$
$a=3k,b=3k+1$
$a=3k,b=3k+2$
$a=3k+1,b=3k+1$
$a=3k+1,b=3k+2$
$a=3k+2,b=3k+2$

So then I would do the addition of all of these pairs and see if they come out in the form of either $3k,3k+1$, or $3k+2$ and if one of them doesn't, then the set is not closed. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is right but you should note that any integer is of one (and only one) of the forms $3k, 3k+1$ or $3k+2$ by the division algorithm.

Comment: Interesting. How would you incorporate that into this proof?

Comment: By the division algorithm any integer have one of the forms $3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$ and that guarantees that when you add all these pairs the result will have one of this forms.

Comment: Do I need to prove the division algorithm or does it suffice to just state that? Do you think a professor might accept an answer like that even though we never proved one that way?

Comment: If you have not proved the division algorithm in the course or in previous courses, maybe you should prove each case by hand. Although it is a classical result commonly proved in first courses.